# How would you merge identical entries in the first column into one entry

Tags: sort, text-formatting

Have a file where the entries are all over the place. 
Example:

```
10.11.12.13  tiger adfa afinhhdddd tiger
10.11.12.13  tiger tiger 123
10.11.12.13  tiger abc
10.11.12.13  tiger abc
10.11.12.13  TIGER ABC

20.21.22.23   hola hola hola123 upside down
20.21.22.23   hola hola hola123 upside DOWN HOLA
20.21.22.23   hola hola hola123 upside down
```

The final output should look like this:

```
10.11.12.13  tiger abc 123 adfa afinhhdddd
20.21.22.23  hola hola123 upside down
```

Comment: This is entirely unclear.   You are asking to sort but it seems like what you really want is to remove unique entries from column 1.  How do you decide which line should be kept?

Comment: It could be the first line as long as there is unique first column. The challenge is sorting and comparing the second/third/... columns so that all entries are on the same line

Comment: Its a hosts file

Comment: Perhaps the question could use some prose to explain what the inputs are and the desired transformation (Ip with unique hostname and aliases?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to want has little to do with sorting, but can be achieved by creating a hash (associative array) keyed on the values of the first column, into which you push case-converted copies of the other columns - which you then de-duplicate and print. In Perl for example

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -alne '
  push @{ $h{shift @F} }, map { lc $_ } @F if $_ =~ /\S/
  }{ 
  foreach $k (sort keys %h) {
    print "$k\t", join " ", uniq @{ $h{$k} } 
  }
' file
```

Ex.:

```
$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -alne '
  push @{ $h{shift @F} }, map { lc $_ } @F if $_ =~ /\S/
  }{ 
  foreach $k (sort keys %h) {
    print "$k\t", join " ", uniq @{ $h{$k} } 
  }
' file
10.11.12.13    tiger adfa afinhhdddd 123 abc
20.21.22.23    hola hola123 upside down
```

If you want a specific order in the output of the array elements, then you will need to provide a rule for that.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!